# delete button c# dataGridView

Tags: c#, database

When selecting a line for deletion, these errors appear, what is the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IAHb.png)

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=E:\desk\new\abusalem\abusalem\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "delete from datauser where id= "+dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    filltable();
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow ibrahim. where is this `cmd` being created/initialized? is it a property of `Page`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a conceptual path to follow. The example is setup for a DataTable, if not using a DataTable but not setting the DataGridView.DataSource consider what is shown below. There is no need to reload the DataGridView once a row has been removed.

Setup a [BindingSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.bindingsource?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) scoped form level, set the DataSource to what you are using to populate the DataGridView currently e.g. a Datatable then dataGridView1.DataSource = someBindingSource. Set the primary key column to hidden so it is not seen.

If no primary key than adjust `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value` the code below to accept that value.

To remove a row, in the button click event. Here I have `Id` as the key.

```
public class Operations
{
    private static string _connectionString =
        @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;" + 
        @"AttachDbFilename=E:\desk\new\abusalem\abusalem\Database1.mdf;" + 
        "Integrated Security=True";

    public static bool Remove(int id)
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand() {Connection = cn})
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "delete from datauser where id=@Id";
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Form code

```
private BindingSource someBindingSource = new BindingSource();
private void RemoveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow row = ((DataRowView)someBindingSource.Current).Row;
    if (Operations.Remove(row.Field<int>("id")))
    {
        someBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
    }
}
```

In the future provide enough code so we have a idea what exactly is being done in regards to how the DataGridView gets loaded.